# Can we reduce executeForDescribe call to db?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, ojdbc

I have been trying to improve my application performance with a technology stack being used is tomcat, spring and hibernate. [snapshot for the application using jvisualvm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFOqO.png)

I have use jvisualvm to monitor the performance of the application(attached in the image) and I found out that the calls for executeForDescribe() method is taking time. Further investigating and going through the documentation the use for executeForDescribe() method is to get the metadata related information of the table.

Correct me if I understand wrong. If possible can we not cache the metadata details at my oracle jdbc driver and stop it from making calls to db for fetching metadata information.

Thread Stuck in following call stack :

```
"http-bio-8280-exec-11" #98 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f7f58012800 nid=0x4c57 runnable [0x00007f7fe0359000]    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:311)
        at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:105)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:305)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:249)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:171)
        at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:89)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:123)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:79)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngineStream.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngineStream.java:429)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:397)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:257)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:587)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:225)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:53)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:943)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:957)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1111)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4798)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:4845)
        - locked <0x00000004df175f08> (a oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1501)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121)
        at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4083)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:116)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1239)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:1097)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:155)
```

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. You do realise that execution needs to talk to the database, and therefor has delays due to roundtrips and work the server has to do. In fact, the screenshots pretty much shows that most time is stuck in a block calling to `SocketInputStream.read()`. If you want to see if that can be improved, talk to your DBA and/or network guys.

Comment: BTW: It doesn't get the metadata for the table, it is getting the metadata for the specific query being executed.